# simplifying a simple boolean expression using lisp

Tags: lisp, boolean-expression

i have a simple **boolean expression** presented as a lisp list like this :
*'(OR 0 (AND A1 A2))*

the previous list is the presentation of ((A1 AND A2)OR 0).

anyway , i am writing a function to simplify this expression ..
for example :

calling the function "reduce" like this :

(reduce '(OR 0 (AND A1 A2)))

would yield

(AND A1 A2)

i firstly tried to create base rules , so i defined 
**the following identities**:

(AND 1 S) == S,

(OR 0 S ) == S,

(AND 0 S) == 0,

( OR 1 S) == 1,

(NOT O) == 1,

(NOT 1) == 0.*

i was thinking of defining 6 functions  , one for each rule , and then
call them one by one in a wrapper , i am new to lisp so i don't have a clue to implement that , i made it in java once , but i dont know how to handle such problem using the syntax of lisp so please help me ..

Comment: You are supposed to put effort into solving that problem yourself... Letting others writing the code for you will not help you learning to program.

Comment: my friend i am so new to lisp and i need the clues , i tried by defining the base rules but my question is how can i use them in a function , how could that be achieved using lisp , that is all what i want ..you are so right , but this is the first time i work with lisp and prologue and i need to see such solutions to learn ..
i couldnt find any sources in the internet on how to evaluate a boolean expression in a recursive list programming environement like lisp , i worked so hard on this and the previous problem , but it seems like lisp is so different , and its hard to debug

Comment: my friend here is a wonderful book for free download, which will teach you Lisp and will show you many examples to learn from. After reading the book, solving the problem will be totally natural: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/index.html
you are so right to search for such resources and luckily your search is over. You've found the book you need to read.

Comment: i will check it now ..thanks my friend

Comment: It depends on which Lisp you are using. If it is Racket, you have the [match function](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html). If it is Common Lisp, you'll have to write more convoluted code, or use an external library, such as [cl-match](https://common-lisp.net/project/cl-match/doc/clmatch.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the complexity of your solution, here's my implementation that's a lot shorter and more readable:

```
(defun reduc (exp)
  (if (atom exp) 
      exp
      (flet ((helper (op args n) ; and and or is nearly the same code so we factor it out
               (let ((newargs (remove n args)) (cn (- 1 n)))
                 (cond
                  ((null newargs) n)
                  ((some (lambda (e) (eql cn e)) newargs) cn)
                  ((null (cdr newargs)) (car newargs))
                  ((cons op newargs))))))
        (let ((op (car exp)) (args (mapcar #'reduc (cdr exp))))
          (ecase op
            ((not) (if (= 1 (length args))
                       (let ((arg1 (car args)))
                         (if (and (numberp arg1) (<= 0 arg1 1)) (- 1 arg1) exp))
                       (error "'not' must have exactly one parameter")))
            ((and) (helper op args 1))
            ((or)  (helper op args 0)))))))
```

Testing:

```
? (reduc '(OR 0 (AND A1 A2))) 
(AND A1 A2)
? (reduc '(OR 0 (AND A1 1 A2)))
(AND A1 A2)
? (reduc '(or ERROR (not 0)))
1
? (reduc '(AND ERROR (not 0)))
ERROR
? (reduc '(OR 0 (AND A1 0))) 
0
? (reduc '(OR 0 (AND A1 1))) 
A1
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider accepting my answer(s) if they completely answer your question(s).

Comment: sure , i am new to SO , i just need to get enough reputations to up vote/down vote answers

Comment: I was not talking about up/downvotes but rather about [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

i finally came up with this solution .

```
(defun simplify (EXPR)
  (simplify-expr NIL EXPR))

(defun simplify-expr (EXPR1 EXPR2)
  (cond 
   ((or (atom EXPR2) (equal EXPR1 EXPR2)) EXPR2)
   (T (simplify-expr EXPR2 (simplify-boolean-expr EXPR2)))))

(defun simplify-boolean-expr (EXPR)
  (cond 
   ((and (equal (first EXPR) `and) (>= (length EXPR) 3)) 
    (simplify-and-expr (rest EXPR)))
   ((and (equal (first EXPR) `or) (>= (length EXPR) 3)) 
    (simplify-or-expr (rest EXPR)))
   ((and (equal (first EXPR) `not) (= (length EXPR) 2)) 
    (simplify-not-expr (rest EXPR)))
   (T 
    (error "~S is not a valid circuit descriptor expression or has an unknown operator." EXPR))))

(defun simplify-and-expr (EXPR)
  (let ((SIMPLIFIED_EXPR (remove `T (remove-duplicates EXPR))))
    (cond 
     ((null SIMPLIFIED_EXPR) `T)
     ((member `NIL SIMPLIFIED_EXPR) `NIL)
     ((null (second SIMPLIFIED_EXPR)) (first SIMPLIFIED_EXPR))
     (T (cons `and (simplify-operand SIMPLIFIED_EXPR))))))

(defun simplify-or-expr (EXPR)
  (let ((SIMPLIFIED_EXPR (remove `NIL (remove-duplicates EXPR))))
    (cond
     ((null SIMPLIFIED_EXPR) `NIL)
     ((member `T SIMPLIFIED_EXPR) `T)
     ((null (second SIMPLIFIED_EXPR)) (first SIMPLIFIED_EXPR))
     (T (cons `or (simplify-operand SIMPLIFIED_EXPR))))))

(defun simplify-not-expr (EXPR)
  (cond 
   ((equal (first EXPR) `NIL) `T)
   ((equal (first EXPR) `T) `NIL)
   ((and (listp (first EXPR)) (equal (first (first EXPR)) `not)) 
    (first (rest (first EXPR))))
   (T (cons `not (simplify-operand EXPR)))))

(defun simplify-operand (OPERAND_LIST)
  (cond 
   ((null OPERAND_LIST) NIL)
   ((atom (first OPERAND_LIST)) 
    (cons (first OPERAND_LIST) (simplify-operand (rest OPERAND_LIST))))
   (T 
    (cons (simplify-expr NIL (first OPERAND_LIST)) (simplify-operand (rest OPERAND_LIST))))))
```

it takes (nil , T) for (0 , 1) and reduces any boolean expression  , i tried it and it works fine .